# Make a copy of file on client's machine from web page

Tags: php, file-upload

I am a PHP developer. I am working on a project in which user has a form. User submit data in fields. In this form, user select an image file.

Now when user click on submit button that time I want to make a copy of selected image at some specific location of user's local machine.

I am not getting idea how to achive this. Can anyone guide me in this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a download, which will be handled by the browser defaults and user actions, and in most cases be downloaded to the users downloads folder.

```
$file = 'path-to-file/your-file-name.png';
$quoted = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($file), '"\\'));
$size   = filesize($file);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$quoted); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.$size);
```